# Most efficient way to process multiple callbacks into one receiver function

Tags: java, callback, synchronization

I have a async API that provides the output via a callback method.

Now, I have to call this API N number of times simultaneously and then wait for N number of hits/callbacks to the callback method.

In order to achieve this,  I have currently used a counter and synchronized the method.

```
@Override
    public synchronized void onResponseReceived() {
       receivedCount++;


        if (receivedCount == totalCount){
            onCallbacksComplete();
        }
    }
```

I was wondering, if there is a faster way to achieve the above?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a textbook case for an executor and a `CountDownLatch` (or `CyclicBarrier` if this gets repeated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html).

```
AtomicInteger receivedCount= new AtomicInteger();
@Override
public void onResponseReceived() {
    if (receivedCount.incrementAndGet() == totalCount){
        onCallbacksComplete();
    }
}
```

or

```
AtomicInteger receivedCount= new AtomicInteger(totalCount);
@Override
public void onResponseReceived() {
    if (receivedCount.decrementAndGet() == 0){
        onCallbacksComplete();
    }
}
```

This avoids the synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

If you are synchronizing the method only to ensure the accuracy of the totalCount variable, you can alternatively use the [Atomic Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) class for the variable, which is thread safe and provide that functionality for you. You could then remove the synchronized modifier for the onResponseReceived method This would make you synchronization block smaller and provide better performance.

You may want to use the Atomic Integer class on the received count as well.

I hope this helps